# BPMN (specific tasks, executed)

Tags: bpmn

i have some questions on the topic BPMN. They are true/false questions and im not sure how to answer them:

1. BPMN diagrams can generally not be executed (i think this is true)
2. BPMN diagrams are specific tasks (no idea on that one...)

can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. BPMN diagrams can be executed by a workflow engine(Process Execution Engine).
2. BPMN diagrams consists of a group of tasks. Each task can be for example a script task or a user task or a call to an API task etc. Also a BPMN diagram can be a part of an other BPMN diagram by declaring it as a subprocess task.

For example, if we have a BPMN diagram which describes the order process  of an item, we may have 3 different tasks in it.

- Submit the order of the item
- Pay for the item
- Deliver item to customer